# How to remove zero columns/rows from a matrix while keeping row/column headings

Tags: matrix

The following `code` (by @kglr) correctly works if `mat1` does not have any row/column headings. However, I am working with a matrix with row/column headings.

How can I adjust the `code` given below to remove the zero rows/columns without dropping the headings?

```
mat1 =
{{0, c1s1, c1s2, c1s3, c2s1, c2s2, c2s3, c3s1, c3s2, c3s3, 
c1d1, c1d2, c2d1, c2d2, c2d3, c3d1, c3d2}, {c1s1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0}, {c1s2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {c1s3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {c2s1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 
2, 1}, {c2s2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
3}, {c2s3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3}, {c3s1,
1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1}, {c3s2, 2, 0, 0, 
2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3}, {c3s3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {c1t, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0,
1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {c2t, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
3, 1, 2}, {c3t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {va, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1}};

nonzerorows = Flatten@Position[mat1, Except@{0 ..}, 1, Heads -> False]
nonzerocols = Flatten@Position[Transpose@mat1, Except@{0 ..}, 1, Heads -> False]
mat1NZ = mat1[[nonzerorows, nonzerocols]]
{zerorows, zerocols} = MapThread[
  Complement[Range@#@Dimensions[mat1], #2] &, {{First, 
  Last}, {nonzerorows, nonzerocols}}]
```

Comment: You can use `nonzerorows = Flatten@Position[mat1, Except@{_, 0 ..}, 1, Heads -> False]` to match nonzero rows starting with a header. The same thing works for columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minimal change in your code:

```
nonzerorows = Flatten@Position[Rest /@ mat1, Except@{0 ..}, 1, Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14}
> ```

```
nonzerocols = Flatten@Position[Rest /@ Transpose@mat1, Except@{0 ..}, 1, 
   Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17}
> ```

```
{zerorows, zerocols} = MapThread[Complement[Range@#@Dimensions[mat1], #2] &, 
  {{First, Last}, {nonzerorows, nonzerocols}}]
```

> ```
>  {{4, 10, 13}, {4, 10, 14}}
> ```

```
mat1NZ = mat1[[nonzerorows, nonzerocols]];

MatrixForm[mat1NZ]
```

[image]

```
MapAt[Highlighted, mat1, 
  Join[Thread[{zerorows, All}], Thread[{All, zerocols}]]] /. 
    Highlighted[Highlighted[a_]] :> Highlighted[a] // MatrixForm
```

[image]